# Effiicient transformation of data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am using the fread package in R to read a very large data set with 600 million rows and 2 columns. The data is read in fine, but when I perform a transpose operation on the table, I get a memory error. The transposed dataset would have around 4 million rows and 20,000 columns.

Code:

```
library(data.table)
#read in data
data = fread("C:/Users/User12/Desktop/train.tsv")
t1 = table(data$Y,data$X)
```

When I run the above code, I get a memory error. Is there an intelligent way to create a frequency table on this large dataset?

Original Table Example:

```
data <- 
  setDT(read.table(text="X    Y
4    5
4    6
4    7
5    5
5    6
5    9", header = T))
```

Output I want:

```
> data[,table(Y,X)]
   X
Y   4 5
  5 1 1
  6 1 1
  7 1 0
  9 0 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alternative I can suggest is:

```
dcast(data[ , .N, by = .(X, Y)], X ~ Y, value.var = "N")
```

But this also fails on a comparable sample set (**warning**: computationally intensive):

```
set.seed(1203)
data <- data.table(X = sample(4e6, 6e8, T), Y = sample(2e4, 6e8, T))
tt <- dcast(data[ , .N, by = .(X, Y)], X ~ Y, value.var = "N")
```

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 298.0 Gb

So you may be out of luck doing this within R (perhaps seek an SQL solution?)

## Update: keyed approach

I think the following could be a viable alternative:

```
setkeyv(data, c("Y", "X"))

lapply(data[ , unique(Y)], function(y) data[.(y), table(X)])
```

Basically, we change the problem into creating a bunch of one-way tables. As long as that can allocate properly, we should be able to `rbind` it into the two-way table you're after.

Barring that, you'll need to consider non-RAM-based alternatives (Spark is a personal favorite, see e.g. [`SparkR`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html) or [`sparklyr`](https://spark.rstudio.com/),  or perhaps SQL-based methods through [`sqldf`](https://www.r-bloggers.com/make-r-speak-sql-with-sqldf/), [`RPresto`](https://github.com/prestodb/RPresto), etc).